# writing the grammar for UTF-16 identifier character in Antlr 4 C++ target

Tags: java, c++, antlr, antlr4, utf-16

I am using [this PostgreSQL grammar](https://github.com/pgcodekeeper/pgcodekeeper/blob/master/apgdiff/antlr-src/SQLLexer.g4) written in Antlr 4 for generating a C++ target parser.

It has some action code written in Java so I need to convert it to C++ so that it will compile.

for the following code I don't understand the meaning:

```
fragment
IdentifierStartChar
    : // these are the valid identifier start characters below 0x7F
    [a-zA-Z_]
    | // these are the valid characters from 0x80 to 0xFF
    [\u00AA\u00B5\u00BA\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u00FF]
    | // these are the letters above 0xFF which only need a single UTF-16 code unit
    [\u0100-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFF] {Character.isLetter((char)_input.LA(-1))}?
    | // letters which require multiple UTF-16 code units
    [\uD800-\uDBFF] [\uDC00-\uDFFF] {Character.isLetter(Character.toCodePoint((char)_input.LA(-2), (char)_input.LA(-1)))}?
    ;
```

What does the question mark `?` after the action code block`{action code}` do? (edit: answered myself below)

It seems to be some kind of letter recognition for the identifier character for UTF-16 encoding.

I was looking for the C++ alternatives for the `Character.isLetter()` and the `Character.toCodePoint()`. Is this a correct way to go? Does the Antlr 4 C++ target work the same way as Java so I only need to swap the function?
Or, how do I modify the code above so that it can work in C++ target?

Answer (score 0):

For the question

> What does the question mark `?` after the action code block`{action code}` do?

I found the answer from the [antlr4 documentation](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/4.8/doc/lexer-rules.md):

> `{«p»}?`  Evaluate semantic predicate «p». If «p» evaluates to false at runtime, the surrounding rule becomes “invisible” (nonviable). Expression «p» conforms to the target language syntax. While semantic predicates can appear anywhere within a lexer rule, it is most efficient to have them at the end of the rule. The one caveat is that semantic predicates must precede lexer actions. See Predicates in Lexer Rules.